# How to add a column with a count result to a sqlalchemy query and pass the pydantic check?

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

### Description

Previously, my query returned the contents of a single *Stories* table. Now I want to add more information: I need to output the *prizes_count* for each Story. There is no field *prizes_count* in the *Stories* table so I made the following query.

```
db.query(models.Stories, func.count(models.Stories.prizes).label("prizes_count")).join(models.Prizes)\
        .group_by(models.Stories.id).all()
```

But I have two problems with it.

1. I get validation errors from Pydantic, because this query returns a list of tuples like `(<database.models.Stories object at 0x0000026BB0055E20>, 1)`. I have to insert the *prizes_count* value into the Stories object or vice versa, pull all fields into the tuple. I can do it manually, of course, but I think there is a better way.
2. With this query I lose all stories with 0 prizes because my join ignores them.

### Code

**endpoint**

```
@app.get("/stories/", response_model=List[schemas.StoryFullInfo])
def get_stories(db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    return crud.get_stories(db)
```

**crud**

```
def get_stories(db: Session):
    return db.query(models.Stories, func.count(models.Stories.prizes).label("prizes_count")).join(models.Prizes)\
        .group_by(models.Stories.id).all()
```

**models**

```
class Stories(Base):
    __tablename__ = "stories"
    id = Column(INTEGER(unsigned=True), primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String(length=128), index=True)
    text = Column(String(length=1000))
    author_id = Column(INTEGER(unsigned=True), ForeignKey("users.id", onupdate="CASCADE", ondelete="CASCADE"),
                       nullable=False)
    status = Column(TINYINT(unsigned=True), server_default="0")
    genre_type = Column(TINYINT(unsigned=True), server_default="0")
    likes_count = Column(INTEGER(unsigned=True), server_default="0")
    image = Column(Text)
    added_to_best_by = Column(INTEGER(unsigned=True))
    creation_DT = Column(DateTime, server_default=func.now())
    change_status_DT = Column(DateTime)

    author = relationship("Users", back_populates="stories")
    comments = relationship("Comments", back_populates="story")
    prizes = relationship("Prizes", back_populates="story")


class Prizes(Base):
    __tablename__ = "prizes"
    id = Column(INTEGER(unsigned=True), primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String(length=128), nullable=False)
    image_id = Column(TINYINT(unsigned=True))
    story_id = Column(INTEGER(unsigned=True), ForeignKey("stories.id", onupdate="CASCADE", ondelete="CASCADE"),
                      nullable=False)
    user_id = Column(INTEGER(unsigned=True), ForeignKey("users.id", onupdate="CASCADE", ondelete="CASCADE"),
                     nullable=False)
    text = Column(String(length=512), nullable=False)
    creation_DT = Column(DateTime, server_default=func.now())

    story = relationship("Stories", back_populates="prizes")
    author = relationship("Users", back_populates="prizes")
```

**schemas**

```
class StoryBaseInfo(BaseModel):
    id: int
    title: str = None
    author_id: int

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


class StoryUpdateInfo(StoryBaseInfo):
    #title: str = None
    text: str = None
    status: int
    genre_type: int
    likes_count: int
    image: str = None
    added_to_best_by: int = None
    change_status_DT: datetime = None

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


class StoryFullInfo(StoryUpdateInfo):

    creation_DT: datetime
    author: UserBaseInfo
    prizes_count: int

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


class PrizeBaseInfo(BaseModel):
    id: int
    story_id: int

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


class PrizeInfo(PrizeBaseInfo):
    title: str
    image_id: int
    text: str
    creation_DT: datetime

    author: UserBaseInfo
    story: StoryBaseInfo

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

Comment: Ref #2: `.join(models.Prizes, isouter=True)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out I was thinking in the wrong direction when I asked this. The problem is solved by the features of SQLAlchemy. I can count prizes by using my configured relationship.
My solution is to add the hybrid property to Stories SQLAlchemy model

```
class Stories(Base):
    __tablename__ = "stories"
    id = Column(INTEGER(unsigned=True), primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String(length=128), index=True)
    text = Column(String(length=1000))
    author_id = Column(INTEGER(unsigned=True), ForeignKey("users.id", onupdate="CASCADE", ondelete="CASCADE"),
                       nullable=False)
    status = Column(TINYINT(unsigned=True), server_default="0")
    genre_type = Column(TINYINT(unsigned=True), server_default="0")
    likes_count = Column(INTEGER(unsigned=True), server_default="0")
    image = Column(Text)
    added_to_best_by = Column(INTEGER(unsigned=True))
    creation_DT = Column(DateTime, server_default=func.now())
    change_status_DT = Column(DateTime)

    author = relationship("Users", back_populates="stories")
    comments = relationship("Comments", back_populates="story")
    prizes = relationship("Prizes", back_populates="story")

    @hybrid_property
    def prizes_count(self):
        return len(self.prizes)
```

And then the following query will satisfy the Pydantic scheme.

```
def get_stories(db: Session):
    return db.query(models.Stories).all()
```

Comment: Hey @Alexander, I have a similar problem when using hybrid_property is hidden on the fast API response.